# Web Page Background

Tags: css

In my project i'm using an image as the background of the body. I'm using the following code in css :-

```
body{
    /*background:#000;*/
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    background:url(../images/stripBG.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
}
```

This background image is strip which i'm repeating in x and y axis to make it appear all over the page. But when some content loads into my page, after certain height, the background is repeating again.
[image: observe the background] 
[image: observe the background repeating again]

How can I make the background so that it is compatible with my dynamic content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of this:

CSS

```
html, body {
    background: url(../images/stripBG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Fm4/1/)

Comment: It's working.But the entire background is turning black. It's not according to my stripBG.jpg.

Comment: Did you change the url to match yours?  I just picked a random image on the internet as an example in the fiddle.

Comment: Try removing any body stylings you have in your current css and replace with the updated code. If the image doesn't show in your page, I would imagine there is a mistake in the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

You have set repeat-y so it will repeat as content height increases. 
try setting the body background color to the second color in the gradient, i think its #845800.
then remove repeat-y

```
body{
    background:#845800;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    background:url(../images/stripBG.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```